# NETLOGO count neighbors with a certain color

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a code that involved having to count the number of neighbors a patch had with the pcolor white. I need to involve these 2 tasks: Death: A cell dies if it is currently living (pcolor white] Birth: A patch is 'born' (turns white) if it has exactly 2 living (pcolor white) neighbors.

Any advice?

Comment: Your first line tells all the white patches to turn green. At that point all your patches are green, so none will have 5 white neighbours. Does it work if you make the first line an `ifelse` instead of `if`?

Comment: Have you played around with the "Life" model from the Cellular Automata section of the model library to get started?